# Erro ao tentar conectar ao banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Estou estudando sobre C# e Asp.net e "tentando" elaborar um projeto de cadastro, alteração e exclusão, seguindo umas vídeos aulas que encontrei na net. O problema é quando vou conectar o Banco de Dados criado anteriormente a aplicação não o encontra e aparece este erro na tela.

[image: Erro Sql]

O erro diz:

> Provider: Named Pipes provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Como resolver este problema?

Comment: GNW-PC é o seu PC ou é um PC que está em rede?

Comment: Aparece alguma base de dados para selecionar no campo "Select or enter a database name:"

Comment: O problema deve estar na tua connection string. Onde é que a definiste? No web.config?

Answer (score 1):

creio que o seu probleam seja os Named Pipes and TCP/IP Connections desabilitados, segue um link com detalhes para os habilitar

https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm

Answer (score 1):

No lugar de `GNW-PC` coloque `.\SqlExpress`